# createBrowserApp is not working with react-navigation v5

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-web, react-navigation-v5

with new react-navigation v5 it's become impossible to use it with react-native-web.
just importing createBrowserApp throws an error

```
import {createBrowserApp} from "@react-navigation/web";
```

show following error in @react-navigation/web/dist/Link.js

```
TypeError: (0 , _core.withNavigation) is not a function
```

does anybody know how to use now react-navigation v5 with react-native-web? I need url history in path, but now it has became impossible.

Answer (score -1):

expo install react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens

```
npm i react-navigation-stack
npm i @react-navigation/web
```

install with expo that is why expo would look for the correct version of the react–navigation libraries that’d work with the expo version that’s installed in your project.

and keep with this tutorial
https://codersera.com/blog/how-to-do-navigation-in-react-native-web-in-2020/